# Can't add spaces, form to email handler

Tags: javascript, php, html

Good morning,

I'm trying to add spaces to the words on my form. Here's an example:

[Sample pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yciv.png)

For example, the "Referralname" and "Phonenumber" should be "Referral Name" and "Phone Number".

Here's the form:

```html
<div class="container">
            <div class="row" style="margin-top: -10px;">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                    <h2>Referral Form <a style="font-size: 10px;" href="../index.php">Back to homepage</a></h2>
                    <p> Send your referrals using the form below and we will get back to you as early as possible. </p>
                    <form role="form" method="post" id="reused_form" enctype=&quot;multipart/form-data&quot; >
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name"> Your Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required maxlength="50">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email"> Referral's Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="referralname" required maxlength="50">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email"> Referral's Email:</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required maxlength="50">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email"> Referral's Phone Number:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="phonenumber" required maxlength="50">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name"> Message:</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" type="textarea" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your Message Here" maxlength="6000" rows="7"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name"> Upload Resumé:</label>
                            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image" name="image" required>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success pull-right" id="btnContactUs">Send! &rarr;</button>
                    </form>
                    <div id="success_message" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none; "> <h3>Sent your message successfully!</h3> </div>
                    <div id="error_message" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none; "> <h3>Error</h3> Sorry there was an error sending your form. </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And here's the php code:

```js
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
/*
Tested working with PHP5.4 and above (including PHP 7 )

 */
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

use FormGuide\Handlx\FormHandler;


$pp = new FormHandler(); 

$validator = $pp->getValidator();
$validator->fields(['name', 'referralname', 'email', 'phonenumber'])->areRequired()->maxLength(50);
$validator->field('email')->isEmail();
$validator->field('message')->maxLength(6000);


$pp->attachFiles(['image']);


$pp->sendEmailTo('angela.sales@teamspan.com', 'marjorie.bugayon@teamspan.com'); // ← Your email here

echo $pp->process($_POST);
```

```js
private function compose_mail($post)
 {
  $content = "Form submission: \n\n";
  foreach($post as $name=>$value)
  {
   $content .= ucwords($name).":\n";
   $content .= "$value\n\n";
  }
  $this->mailer->Body  = $content;
 }
```

Sorry if my question isn't good, trying my best to make a good question.

Comment: So, what's your question? Everything seems pretty fine.

Comment: I wanted to add space to the words, for example the, "Referralname" should be "Referral Name" @ChukwuemekaInya

Comment: I'm not sure where it's dispaying incorrectly. Is it the "Referral's Name" in the html code that you are referring to (it's "Referral's" not "Referral")? And if that's the case, I'm not sure why you are displaying the php code.

Comment: @Andri there should be a space between Referralname. So Referralname should be Referral Name

Comment: But there is no "Referral Name" in your code. Just "**Referral's** Name". Is that what you mean?

Comment: Ok, you post what you want, now please post as an image what you have pointing out the differences. As far as I see, there must be no problems with the spacing in the words you mention, plus the exact labels differ from your pic to your code.

Comment: The only place you need to add space is in the HTML form which you did. Don't add space to those `fields` name. You are only gonna cause trouble for yourself along the line. Leave it as is.

Comment: @Dknacht What do you mean? The pic says Referralname. What I want to happen is Referral "SPACE" Name.

Comment: `$validator->fields(['name', 'referralname', 'email', 'phonenumber'])` ... You don't need spaces here.

Comment: @Renzo is this live on the web (do you have a link?)

Comment: @ChukwuemekaInya yeah, but on the email i need the spaces.

Comment: @Andri No sorry it's an intranet website

Comment: But the code says `Referral's Name:`. Look, to go short a space in HTML can be added with the following code `&nbsp;`you can read about it here: https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/n/nbsp.htm

Comment: I actually found it here: https://www.teamspan.com/core/referrals/formpage.html  (using the emails in your code) but there are spaces visible there, so I must be misunderstanding the question.

Comment: @Dknacht Yes, that's with the form. But when I get the email it doesn't have space in the middle

Comment: @Andri Yes sorry, the picture was the email, the form is good but when I get the email it doesn't have any spaces

Comment: Then you must show us the code that is generating the email, because is there where you have the problem. I think you are concatenating somewhere something wrong.

Comment: Yes, the code for the email is missing. (FormHandler class)

Comment: @Dknacht I added the email composition code, sorry about that

Comment: @Andri Sorry, I added the email composition code,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
private function compose_mail($post)
    {
        $content = "Form submission: \n\n";
        foreach($post as $name=>$value)
        {
            $content .= ucwords($name).":\n";
            $content .= "$value\n\n";
        }
        $content = str_replace("Referralname", "Referral Name", $content);
        $content = str_replace("Phonenumber", "Phone number", $content);
        $this->mailer->Body  = $content;
    }
```

Comment: It's a very simplified solution. But should do the trick. It's simply doing "find and replace" in the text after the code is done, but it would make it work.

Comment: I'm just adding this code: $content = str_replace("Referralname", "Referral Name", $content);
to the compose_mail function.
If you want to replace more text, you can just add more of those lines.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

"Referral's Name" is a label. It's only good for user interaction. Your PHP code never sees it.

"referralname" is the name of an INPUT control of type "text". This is what your code uses.

You can't (or at least shoudn't) add spaces and punctuation to a field name. There's no need for them to be identical.

Comment: The form is good, but when I get the email, I dont get the spaces between. Please see attached email composition code

Comment: Are you talking about the email address? 

Do want "First Last <firstlast@example.org>"?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want that space **in the body of the e-mail**. So try this adding these 2 lines in php:

```
        $content = str_ireplace('Referralname', 'Referral Name', $content);
        $content = str_ireplace('Phonenumber', 'Phone Number', $content);

        //right before this line:
        $this->mailer->Body  = $content;
```

Php function [str_ireplace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) will replace the first string with the second, but only in the body of e-mail.

Str_ireplace or str_replace should be the same for you. The former is case-insensitive, the latter is case-sensitive.